# adding css and js file in laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel

I want to include a css all css and js in single page and load it in all page.Now If I want to include bootstrap.css and  bootstrap.js in welcome page I have included in welcome.blade.php page and if i want to add in another page I have included in second.blade.php page also.I want to include it in master page

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Crate a separate header.blade and include css and js. Then extends in each page

Comment: can I include one blade.php in another page?

Comment: Yes.. below I share my code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Crate header.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>dhinchakwale</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="{{ asset('/css/datepicker.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link href="{{ asset('/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">    
    <!-- Custom CSS -->  
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/admin.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>    
  </head>

  <body id="page-top">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->        
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img alt="Brand" src="{{asset('/images/logo.png')}}" class="img-brand"></a>
        </div>      
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="content-div">
      @yield('content')
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>  

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script> 
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js') }}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And use like this
First extends header
Second Section of your content

```
@extends('layouts.header')
@section('content')
  <section class="content-header">
    <h1>
      Hello
    </h1>
  </section>
@stop
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the steps you can follow

1. Create a master template layout
2. Extend the master template in all pages and paste your link into header section

To create a master template
//master.blade.php

```
<html lang="en">

      @yield('header')

<body>
      @yield('page-body')
</body>
</html>
```

Now Extend this layout in second.blade.php

```
@extend('master.blade')
@section('header')
   <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endsection
@section('page-body')
   {{!-- content of body --}}
@endsection
```

Answer (score 3):

Define a common layout and include all .js and .css file on that layout and than bind your page with this layout.

Layout:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where: @yield directive is used to display the contents of a given section.

View:

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')
    i am the home page
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a master layout view file then define your CSS and JS there. Then all of your view file will extend that layout file. See documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade